# Ошибка при инициализации VisualElement

Tags: c#, wpf, классы

Всем добрый вечер! Пытаюсь инициализировать новый VisualElement элемент, но почему-то он остается пустым. Как такое может быть?
Ниже привожу код как это делаю

```
            VisualElement vs = new VisualElement
            {
                X = MapsElement._PositionX,
                Y = MapsElement._PositionY,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                UIElement = new System.Windows.Controls.Image
                {
                    Source = new BitmapImage(uri),
                    Width = MapsElement._ElementWidth,
                    Height = MapsElement._ElementHeight,
                    Opacity = opacity,
                    IsHitTestVisible = true
                }
            };
```

Comment: А что за класс `VisualElement`?

Comment: А Вы его добавили в VisualTree?